# Can a debug-apk be reverse engineered to make it a release-apk?

Tags: decompilation, unpacking, android, copy-protection, apk

I am making a system in which the users can create Android applications. I want them to give an option to download a [debug apk](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html#DebugMode) so that they can try it out first. After that, they have to pay for it to get the [apk in release mode](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html#ReleaseMode), so that it can be distributed in the Google Play Store.

I of course don't want them to be able to reverse-engineer the debug apk so that they can extract the needed files from it and then sign it themselves. Hence my question:

**Is it possible to reverse engineer a debug apk to extract the classes and everything needed to build it in release mode?**

If so, would there be any way to secure the debug versions so that it isn't possible anymore?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between a debug apk and a release apk is that a debug apk is signed by a particular key which is provided with the SDK, whereas a release apk is signed by some other key. There's nothing to reverse engineer: all you have to do to make a release apk and sign it.

Nobody but you can create an apk signed by you. But anyone can make their own release apk by signing them.

A solution in your case would be to produce a binary including some DRM and refuse to run except on your customer's pre-registered device. How to implement such DRM, especially while letting your customer debug his applications, is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Of course, we all know how reliable client side DRM is.

Comment: @Antimony I didn't say it was an easy (or indeed solvable) exercise.

Comment: @Antimony: I don't understand the solution.can you please explain it?